# how to fix 'NoNode for /hbase/master'

Tags: hadoop, hbase

I've already done a cluster Hadoop with 3 nodes (hadoop-master, hadoop-data1, hadoop-data2). This seems to work but then when I try to install hbase on it, I still get an error when I do this on hbase shell

```
status
```

here is the hbase-site.xml config:

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://hadoop-master:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>/usr/local/zookeeper</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>hadoop-master</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

and the cluster seems to work because I can acces to
http://IP_OF_MY_MASTER_NODE:8088/cluster/nodes
and here is what I get with jps

```
hadoop@hadoop-master:~$ jps
29713 ResourceManager
29029 NameNode
29893 NodeManager
29480 SecondaryNameNode
30568 HQuorumPeer
29213 DataNode
31101 Jps
```

```
hadoop@hadoop-data1:~$ jps
29348 Jps
28665 DataNode
28842 NodeManager
```

Here is my actual result:

```
hadoop@hadoop-master:~$ /home/hadoop/hbase/hbase-2.1.4/bin/hbase shell
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/usr/local/hadoop/share/hadoop/common/lib/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/hadoop/hbase/hbase-2.1.4/lib/client-facing-thirdparty/slf4j-log4j12-1.7.25.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.Log4jLoggerFactory]
HBase Shell
Use "help" to get list of supported commands.
Use "exit" to quit this interactive shell.
For Reference, please visit: http://hbase.apache.org/2.0/book.html#shell
Version 2.1.4, r5b7722f8551bca783adb36a920ca77e417ca99d1, Tue Mar 19 19:05:06 UTC 2019
Took 0.0033 seconds                                                                                                
hbase(main):001:0> status

ERROR: KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/master
```

Thank's in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because **HMaster process** is not running. Check in **jps**.

In `$HBASE_HOME/logs` directory check for `hbase-***-master.log` for specific error.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61387564/5766301) as well.